# How to get React setState to re-render for Foundation 6 Reveal (Modal)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, zurb-foundation

My issue has been touched in a few questions around the web but I don't think it's been holistically asked.

I am using Foundation 6 with React. Everything works by using

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
let foundation = require('path/to/foundation.js');
```

then in `componentDidUpdate()`, I call `$(document).foundation()`. Also, the CSS is being called somewhere.

My problem is once I get the modal to open, I can't populate it with data using `setState()`. I think I understand that the DOM changes when the modal opens, thus causing issues but I was wondering if anyone has had success with the Reveal plugin? My code is like this:

```
getData() {
    Facebook.get('/me/taggable_friends', function(error, response) {
        $('#modal').foundation('open');
        
        //setTimeout is just for testing sanity
        let _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            _this.setState({ friends: response.data });
        }, 3000);
    })
}
```

Again, everything works. I'm getting data back from Facebook, the state is updating, the modal is opening, I'm just not able to populate the modal and I have this as my markup:

```
<div id="modal" className="modal-classes-from-foundation" data-reveal>
    {
        this.state.friends.length > 0 &&
        this.state.friends.map((friend, i) => {
            return(
                <div>{ friend.name }</div>
            )
        })
    }
</div>
```

Also to note, `this.state.friends` is being set in the constructor as an empty array.

**All the code is valid on my server (no errors), but I wrote this from memory so I didn't remember small details like class/path names**

### Things I tried

- Using `componentWillReceiveProps` to force update
- Setting state before calling modal open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think your answer is so smart. AFAIK the current state of the art is to set a nodeReference using a setNode method and then have

```
ref={this.setNode}
```

in your element, so then you can call whatever you are calling with jQuery, passing it via argument the node so you can play with it, and use the React lifecycle hooks to sync your react world with your jQuery playground

```
componentWillMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize, false);
}

componentDidMount() {
  //initialize your jQuery dom manipulation
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (!this.props.store.equals(nextProps)) {
    //to update stuff
  }
  return false; //> dont update
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  //
}

setNode(ref) {
  this.nodeReference = ref;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The [React docs back it up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and I was able to add dynamic state data to it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against a virtual desk for a day, I understand why it's tough getting Reveal to work with React, especially compared to the other Foundation elements.

Reveal is an overlay that lives inside of `<body></body>` but not inside `<div id="app"></div>`, or whatever you name the root div that your React app renders to. Since the overlay is outside of the "app", React has no control over it and sending states/props to it won't do anything.

What I ended up doing is a bit clever and could be looked down upon, but seemed very necessary. I took inspiration from [BlackMutt](http://blackmuttmedia.com/blog/a-kinder-gentler-reactjs-foundation-reveal-modal/) in 2015 where he basically created a function to use jQuery for appending the modal's code and initializing it. Unfortunately, this means every other thing you do with the modal will need to use jQuery as well but the good news is that it's separated from the rest of the app. Here's a sample of what it looks like:

```
createListModal(items) {
    let content = items.map((item, i) => {
        return $('<div class="list-item"><div class="item-name">'+ item.name +'</div></div>');
    });
    let close = $('<button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>');
    let modal = $('<div class="reveal" id="list-popup" data-reveal>').append(content).append(pagination).append(close);
    $(modal).foundation();

    $('#list-popup').foundation('open');
}
```

So all I did was call that method when I got my data from Facebook. It's pretty simple but if you've been in React for a while, you have to switch your brain back into thinking in jQuery again.